# Rails Devise Auto_Gen Password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using the Devise gem for my sign-up process - I only want the email to be required, so I'm auto-generating a password for every user.

For some reason, my code is creating 2 database entries for a single user. One -- with the email address. One -- with just the encrypted password.

User.rb

```
password = Devise.friendly_token
  User.create!(:email => @current_user_email, :id => @current_user_id, :password => password, :password_confirmation => password)


  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

Comment: Why are you specifying the `id`? In almost all cases, the `id` column should be set automatically by the database. Also, I assume the top 2 rows are in the controller, and the bottom 3 are in the model? Where are the `@current_user_email` etc. variables coming from?

Comment: I was specifying the id to see if it would pass the `current_user` parmeters (from Devise's helper) properly. I have all this code in the model btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of my projects, I took a similar path in not requiring the user to register with a password. It has resulted in some major headaches and UX shenanigans FWIW.

Whatever you're using for persistence, make sure to set a unique index on the email column. This will cause exceptions, but they're easily handled.

I'd suggest a class method in your user model like:

```
class User
  def self.create_without_password!(email)
    password = Devise.friendly_token
    User.create!(:email => email.downcase, :password => password, :password_confirmation => password)
  end
end
```

That should validate the model without using the before_save callback and raise an exception on non-uniqueness

Comment: not working for me - now, the password simply isn't being stored in the database. Looks like it might be placement of this code. I tried creating a Registration Controller and overwriting the `create` method.